# keras Sequential().predict return nan

Tags: keras, predict, sequential

I tried to build a neural network which has 1 hidden layer and 4 nodes for the hidden layer.

```
toyes = Sequential()
toyes.add(Dense(units = 4, activation = 'linear', input_dim = 5))
toyes.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'linear'))
```

and I did compiling and fitting. FYI, 'x_train' and 'y_train' is a pandas.DataFrame.
x_train contains X1,X2,X3,X4,X5 and y_trains contains Y
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLueS.png)

```
toyes.compile(loss = 'mean_squared_error', optimizer = SGD(lr=1))
toyes.fit(x_train.values, np.asarray(y_train).reshape(-1,1), epochs = 1500, verbose=0)
```

and I finally got nan... but I don't understand the result although I match the input type as an array, not pandas!

```
toyes.predict(x_test.values)

[[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]
[nan]]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2uLs.png)

please let me know the way to get correct!

Answer (score 0):

Set a lower learning rate.

```
SGD(lr=0.001)
```

If there are nan values in df, it might cause this problem too.

```
toyes = Sequential()
toyes.add(Dense(5,activation=‘relu’))
toyes.add(Dense(4,activation=‘relu’))

toyes.add(Dense(1))

toyes.compile(loss=‘mse’,optimizer=SGD(lr=0.001)
```

I recommend using relu, and more understandable inputs!

Comment: it doesnt work .. still have the same problem that the result only has nan

Comment: could you please share an ex of df?

Comment: I uploaded the image of df !

Comment: X1           X2     X3     X4   X5    Y
0 0.00632 2.31 0.538 6.575 65.2 24.0
1 0.02731 7.07 0.469 6.421 78.9 21.6
2 0.02729 7.07 0.469 7.185 61.1 34.7
3 0.03237 2.18 0.458 6.998 45.8 33.4
4 0.06905 2.18 0.458 7.147 54.2 36.2